How to properly implement login and token handling from REST endpoint in ASP.NET Core/MAUI Blazor
I'm developing a MAUI Blazor application that communicates with a Django REST Framework backend. I'm trying to implement user authentication, but I'm encountering a "Bad Request" error when trying to log in.
I'm successfully hitting the /api/login/ endpoint, but I'm getting a "Bad Request" error. What could be causing this? How should I format the request to ensure successful authentication?
Here's the relevant part of my Blazor code:
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient HttpClient
@using System.Text
@using mysocial.Models
@using Newtonsoft.Json

<h3>Login</h3>

<div>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" @bind="username" />
</div>

<div>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" @bind="password" />
</div>

<button @onclick="Logins">Login</button>

@if (authToken != null)
{
    <p>Login successful! Token: @authToken.Token</p>
}

@code {
    private string? username;
    private string? password;
    private AuthToken? authToken;

    private async Task Logins()
    {
        var loginData = new
        {
            Username = username,
            Password = password
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginData);
        var response = await HttpClient.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/",
            new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            authToken = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AuthToken>();
        }
        else
        {
            var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {errorContent}");
        }
    }
}


You could try this
var loginData = new
{
    username = "username",
    password = "password"
};

var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/", loginData);

And ensure the backend allow the blazor domain orgins.
